# What does %{ } mean?

Tags: html, hibernate, jsp, struts2, struts

I'm new to some Java technologies; I'm trying to use a combination of struts, hibernate, and jQuery. I'm trying to figure out what does the `%{}` means in the following line of code:

```
<s:set name="tableModel" value="%{tableModel}" />
```

Comment: The answers are correct, although it's a bit weird to use it like this, since it just creates a named stack context variable that's already available--it may have been an attempt at optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/420711/Struts/Struts-or) this questions was asked. According to Sonny Gill there:

> %{} syntax is used to force OGNL evaluation where Struts would otherwise be treating the value as a String literal.

**Other Resources:** [Apache Struts OGNL Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/ognl.html)

Answer (score 2):

%{expression} is a OGNL escape sequence, that signals to the framework when to process the expression as an expression rather than interpreting it as a string literal.

`%{tableModel}` pulls the corresponding value from the OGNL `ValueStack`, which "normally" results in calling a `getTableModel()` function of your current action (depending on what's on the `ValueStack`).